# Moved files only opening as 'read-only' in Excel

Tags: windows-xp, microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2003, read-only

I moved a large directory of Excel files to another machine.  When I sign in as myself (**administrator signing into domain**) then the files open just fine, but when I sign in as a **Power User directly onto the machine**, the files open as '**Read-Only**'.

I've reset all the attributes through both Windows and DOS, but to no avail.  Also I checked on the Search Indexing bug, but indexing is already turned off.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that when the files copied, Power Users wasn't on the permissions list (though Users was).  So I added them to the list and all is copasetic.

I've heard that if I just copy the files in under the specific account, instead of being signed in as myself, that it will work that way also.  I'll try that next time.